# Asking Excel to Provide with the max value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Lets say there are two columns

```
VAR   DATA
 A     12
 B     20
 C     45
 D     35
 E     25
 F     20
```

It is wanted that excel gives an output for VAR which has the highest value. So in the case above, Excel should give an output in a cell of C since it has the value of 45.

The way I am doing it now is the following:

I manually find the max value using the max() command. Once I know the max value then using the Filter I find that value in the table/dataset and manually define it in a different cell. I do the same for max and min. I was wondering if there is a faster and automated way of doing this, so that I can analyse more than one dataset at a time.

I have been trying to do this with an IF command, but I could not figure out how to state the statement in terms of max value.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic INDEX/MATCH pair will do this if you look for a MATCH to the MAX value in the *Data* column.

```
=INDEX(A:A, MATCH(MAX(B:B), B:B, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! It works flawlessly!